# How to detect source filetype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Quite simply, is there anyway to detect what file type a source file is?

Context:
I have an HTML5 audio element and depending on what button someone clicks I want to randomly change the source of that audio element using JavaScript (please, no jQuery solutions) so that different songs will play. I have several hundred sound files, so I really don't want to have to convert them all to one file type.
I currently have a method that gets a random but always correct file name via a RNG but no way of knowing the file extension this file is (it could be .ogg, .wav, .m4a or .mp3). It just tries every possible extension until one works but am having a bit of trouble with the error handling which is causing other issues to occur so it would be really great if you could help me out here with a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: create a serverside script that indexes the file system, that way you have an easy way of knowing the filenames and extensions.

Comment: I really can't work the server side at the moment. Learning how to is a little further down my to do list and I honestly don't have time right now.

Comment: Then you could use ajax and do a head request to check if the file exists, but you would still have to check all the file extensions as you can't list the directory with clientside code

Answer (score 0):

```
// fileInput is an HTML input element: <input type="file" id="myfileinput" multiple>
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");

// files is a FileList object (similar to NodeList)
var files = fileInput.files;
var file;

// loop trough files
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    // get item
    file = files.item(i);
    //or
    file = files[i];

    alert(file.type);
}
```

[developer.mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixture of the new [XMLHttpRequest Level 2 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) to check the file type of a server resource.

For example, to get the type of an image:

```
url = '/favicon.ico';
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var file = this.response;
        alert(file.type);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

[**<kbd>JSFIDDLE demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/5uLnwmxf/1/)